# Is there a free extension for Safari that displays the viewport size

Tags: html, css, safari, responsive-design, viewport

I've got a nice extension for chrome ('Window Resizer') that displays the viewport size, but I don't know how to clear the cache in chrome without using my mouse so I tend to use Safari for browser development.

I've looked around a bit and I can't seem to find an extension that displays the viewport size in Safari (I can find various extensions that allow me to set the viewport size, but none that display it when I change it manually).

Does anyone know of a free extension that does this?

Comment: Please don't vote to close. This is a valid question. Safari is a tool used by developers as described in the first section of guidance on what can be asked here - http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: I don't know about any viewport extensions for Safari. But I do however know a quick way to clear cache in chrome: **CMD+shift+backspace** and **CMD+shift+delete** on Windows.

Comment: Thanks Natalie - In the past Chrome then forced me to click 'Clear browsing data' button. It looks like I can get past that window by hitting return. It's still an overly lengthly process -

    **CMD+shift+backspace** -> 
    **return** ->
    **cmd+w**

But it's much better than using the mouse - I think I'll start using Chrome more. Thanks!

Comment: Use this: http://viewportsizes.com/

Answer (score 4):

This free Safari Extensions shows the viewport width and height while resizing:

https://github.com/kevinoes/viewportSize-safari-extension

Comment: Actually, just discovered that this one blocks the Twitter widget from rendering for some reason. Too bad. :(

Answer (score 3):

If you need the current size, an easy way is to open the Web Inspector (Cmd-Alt-I). Select the `<html>` node. then click on the Metrics inspector on the right to see the current viewport width/height. This doesn't update very fast if you're resizing the window, but can still give you an estimate of the size.

Answer (score 1):

One solution I've come across is to use a site called http://www.resizemybrowser.com.

I have this open in another a tab in safari and refer to it to get the current viewport size.

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is pretty old but here's what I do. It might help someone.

Just use a bit of jquery:

```
$(window).resize(function(){
    var viewportWidth = $(window).width();
    var ems = viewportWidth / parseFloat($("body").css("font-size"));
    $('#viewport').html(viewportWidth+" | "+ems);
});
```

Then a bit of css

```
#viewport {
  background: #000000;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 15px;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 100;
  color: $white;
}
```

Shame safari doesn't work more like chrome and show you but I just stick this on every project and it works great. I tend to put some logic on the #viewport div that only shows if i'm logged in so it doesn't affect the live site

Answer (score 0):

Safari's dev tools now has "Enter Responsive Design Mode".  If you have dev tools enabled, then go to Safari's toolbar Develop > Enter Responsive Design Mode.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a console-based solution inspired by @cshelswell's answer, but that doesn't require JQuery.

Just paste this into the Console and it'll start printing the window size and ratio (to 16) in the console every time you resize.

```
window.onresize = function() {
    var w = window.visualViewport.width;
    var h = window.visualViewport.height;
    var ratioTop = 16;
    var ratioBottom = (16 * h) / w;
    console.log(`${w} x ${h} (${ratioTop}:${ratioBottom})`);
}
```